# Jquery - Attempting to retrieve output from php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

This is my first attempt at AJAX and am unable to retrieve the output from the data.php file.

Here is the code so far, not all code is included, just what is applicable:

index.php

```
<article class="post">
    <form name="form"><input type="hidden" name="postid" value="<?php echo $value['post_id'];?>" />
   </article>

<div id="main-post">
<div id="gotpostid">some text</div>
</div>
```

.js file

```
$(".cover-img").click(function(){
    $("#main-post").fadeIn(1000);
    $.post("data.php", {postid: form.postid.value},
        function(output){
              $("#gotpostid").html(output).show();
    });   
 });
```

data.php

```
<?php

    echo 'got this from data.php';
?>
```

the data.php file is in the same directory as the .js.

Currently when I click on the image it shows the "main-post" div but the "gotpostid" within it still only displays the "some text" and doesn't replace it with the output text from the php file.

This is the result of adding the following code:

```
.fail(function(x,y,z){ $("#gotpostid").html(x + "<br />" + y + "<br />" + z)})
```

> [object Object] error Not Found

I found the error mostly thanks to Kevin B's suggestion for adding the .fail().

The url wasn't correct for the .php file, it should have been `js/data.php`.

Comment: might want to take a look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Your code looks fine. What is it doing/not doing?

Comment: @Kevin B Hi, I added an explanation to the bottom.

Comment: Modify your `$.post` to `$.post(url,{...},function(...){...}).fail(function(x,y,z){ $("#gotpostid").html(x + "<br />" + y + "<br />" + z)})` and post the response of it in your question. (note: all i added was `.fail(handler)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a error method to your ajax handler to know if something unexpected is happening

```
$(".cover-img").click(function(){
    $("#main-post").fadeIn(1000);
    var jqxhr = $.post("/echo/html/", {postid: form.postid.value},
        function(output){
              $("#gotpostid").html(output).show();
    })
    .error( function()
    {
        console.log( "error" );      
    })

    return false;
 });​
```

Answer (score 0):

Install FireBug if not already done, and do a console.log(output) inside you response function. Do you see your response?